# Tensorflow: Attempting to use uninitialized value RNN/GRUCell/Gates/Linear/Bias

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, lstm

#### Environment info

Operating System:
Rocks OS (Centos 6.5)

I installed from sources, and here is my version:
https://github.com/shiyemin/tensorflow/
Nothing changed but to make it compile successfully on our server.

#### ERROR

I use caffe-tensorflow to convert caffe model to tensorflow and the GoogLeNet is selected to construct our network.

I add  a LSTM layer to this code as follows:

```py
@layer
def lstm(self, input, lstm_type, n_steps, initial_state, num_units, name):
    #  with tf.variable_scope(name) as scope:
    input_shape = input.get_shape()
    dim = 1
    for d in input_shape[1:].as_list():
        dim *= d
    input = tf.reshape(input, [input_shape[0].value, -1])

    # select LSTM type, Define a lstm cell with tensorflow
    if lstm_type == 'basic':
        lstm_cell = rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(num_units, input_size=dim)
    elif lstm_type == 'lstm':
        lstm_cell = rnn_cell.LSTMCell(num_units, input_size=dim)
    elif lstm_type == 'GRU':
        lstm_cell = rnn_cell.GRUCell(num_units, input_size=dim)
    else:
        raise ValueError("LSTM type %s error."%lstm_type)

    # Split data because rnn cell needs a list of inputs for the RNN inner loop
    input = tf.split(0, n_steps, input) # n_steps * (batch_size, n_hidden)

    # Get lstm cell output
    outputs, states = rnn.rnn(lstm_cell, input, initial_state=initial_state) # , scope=scope)
    outputs = tf.concat(0, outputs)
    return outputs #, states
```

When i add this LSTM layer to GoogLeNet, the following error occurs.

```
Failed precondition: Attempting to use uninitialized value  RNN/GRUCell/Gates/Linear/Bias
```

But when i using the code from:

https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/master/examples/3%20-%20Neural%20Networks/recurrent_network.py,

everything works well.

Anyone knows what happened? I don't know how to debug this error.

Comment: Where do you 'add it' ?

Comment: Please see https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1390. I submit an issue to tensorflow to get more help. However, nobody answers until now.